# how to validate exclation symbol in pregmatch

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a string `$str = "GO(P)2005/Fin!2005-01-05";`
Here exclamation is mandatary and in first part before the exclamation  can be alpha,numeric,small brackets ,/ and space and the second part after exclamation must be a date.

My regular expression is like this

```
/^[[:alpha:][:space:][:digit:]\/.\!()-]$/
```

But it is not working .please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
preg_match('~^[a-zA-Z0-9()/\s]+!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$~', $string, $match);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
preg_match('/(?:.*)!(?:.*)/sim', $string)
```